# Error during BDD-Test for Android: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No compose hierarchies found in the app

Tags: kotlin, automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose, bdd, android-espresso

I have bdd-test for my app , I use compose and espresso, and I have this error :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No compose hierarchies found in the app. Possible reasons include: (1) the Activity that calls setContent did not launch; (2) setContent was not called; (3) setContent was called before the ComposeTestRule ran. If setContent is called by the Activity, make sure the Activity is launched after the ComposeTestRule runs.

This is a part of my code:
@WithJunitRule
class ComposeRuleHolder {

```
   companion object {
       lateinit var composeTestRule: ComposeTestRule
   }

   @Rule(order = 0)
   @JvmField
   var composeRule: ComposeTestRule = createEmptyComposeRule()

   @Before
       fun before() {
       composeTestRule = composeRule
     }
}
```

and after in the class for the test:

```
fun myPage(func: MyPage.(ComposeTestRule) -> Unit) = MyPage.apply {
    func(
        ComposeRuleHolder.composeTestRule
    )
 }

@OptIn(ExperimentalTestApi::class)
object MyPage { ...
   ....
}
```

This was working but from about 2 weeks I had this error :
Any Idea?
Thanks